# 301 redirect htaccess subfolder problem

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am having a problem getting some of my 301 redirects to work correctly in htaccess.

The problem is the subfolders on the new link do not line up:
 Redirect 301 /properties/available-properties/filename.html http://www.domain.com/index.php/properties/available/new-filename

the problem is that it returns the path of:
www.domain.com/index.php/properties/availablefilename.html

any suggestions?

Comment: What rewrite rules are you using?

Comment: No rewrite rules currently, just Redirect 301

Comment: Is there something in the logs regarding this issue?

Comment: Let me clarify... I think it is the mismatched sub folders or going from .html to an extensionless link.
i.e. /properties/a/available-properties/filename.html where I added the /a/ correctly redirects 
What is weir is that if I add a folder on the old directory then the redirect works. 
i.e.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so I'm going to take a shot in the dark, did you mean to put

```
Redirect 301 /properties/available-properties/filename.html http://www.domain.com/properties/available/new-filename
```

*Dropping the "index.php/" since this may of been in error?